# Can my game be 8-bit even though it has hi-res text?

Tags: graphics, graphics-programming

[image: My Game's Select level Screen]

My game has 8-bit sounds, 8-bit graphics, 8-bit everything. Except one thing: the level selection screen. It has small text and therefore must be hi-res to be readable. What should I do?
**Edit:** The arrows on either side of 'select level' are for going to multiple level screens when there is more levels to be shown. A great answer has been given, but more are welcome.

Comment: 8-bit doesn't refer to the resulotion, it only refers to the color depth. 8 bit means 256 colors.

Comment: @Bálint  8-bit here references an aesthetic; to replicate the look and feel of the 8 bit era. (I'd argue that 8 bit would mean a "16 color palette" as most of the machines at that time displayed 4 to 16 colors on screen at the same time). Same goes for 8-bit sound which means usually "chip-tunes" and so on.

Comment: @Felsir Yes, they could only display 4 to 16 colors at a time to save memory, but they could choose from different color schemes.

Comment: @Bálint *some* of them could. Still as said, it is about the aesthetic. In some cases it goes further than just graphics but also sound and/or controls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we think of 8-bit games, we often think of the 8-bit era, where the graphic style was the result of the obvious hardware constraint. In today's age, 8-bit is often associated with a graphical design that *replicates* these games. They do not necessarily restrict themselves to the same native resolutions. In fact, most standard hardware natively runs much larger resolutions. So in fact, a higher resolution that still *bases* its graphical design in 8-bit is still common - and still considered "8-bit".

Given that you are displaying information relevant to the level, itself, you have to consider the trade-off in redesigning the interface to use "8-bit" text. You could try conveying the information in a non-textual format; icons are a popular choice. But it is far easier to miss the mark in expecting your users to understand the information, where as the text itself is straight forward, and you can assume greater understanding across a wider range of users.

Is your game any less of an 8-bit game for using high-resolution text? Maybe. I would argue it is a semantic difference - too insignificant to really impact the 8-bit feel. Is your game still 8-bit for using it? Definitely. From what you explain, the rest of the game is entirely 8-bit. To say the text excludes it is simply nit-picking. If the game is good, and still has an 8-bit feel, most users won't care.

In your current case, you have made the trade-off of a small degree of graphical consistency for far more significant general usability. Your game will profit far more from users being able to understand your text and what it conveys about the level, and if your game is fun and enjoyable, the miniscule amount of "high-res" resource should not detract from the general 8-bit feel.

**I say leave it, it works well**.

If you're still concerned, *ask your users*. Get some playtests, and ask the users some non-probing questions concerning their opinions, their impression of "what genre is this" (given that 8-bit is now considered a genre of its own - some users may not even consider 8-bit a genre, so try to have some more experienced gamers in your testing), and their impressions of the overall style. At the end, you can ask more direct questions. Start with questions that do not infer any specific answer (dont start with "do you think this is 8-bit"), so you can achieve a more natural impression.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I have decided to keep the text but still get playtesters just in case. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could add arrows to cycle thru multiple slides with only a couple levels on each one. Maybe 3 per a slide? Thiis way you could divide the game into multiple "acts".